# Git diff gives me a fatal: bad revision 'HEAD~1'

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'm trying to check which files have changed previously in a github action. For this I'm running the following command:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~1 -- .'
```

While this works locally, on github actions I seem to get this error:

```
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD~1'
Checking if any files changed
```

I'm using the https://github.com/actions/checkout action for doing the checkout.

Answer (score 14):

So I managed to solve it. Apparently the action package I used seems to only fetch the last commit, hence giving the error where it cannot find the other commits when I look for them. The fix was to actually fetch more than one version, this is what I'm doing now in my action, and it works:

```
...
steps:
 - name: Checkout code
   uses: actions/checkout@v2
   with:
     fetch-depth: 5
...
```